# One IP Address and Wildcard Certificate for multiple Virtual Hosts (Windows, Apache 2.4.2, OpenSSL 1.0.2e)

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4, https, openssl

I have searched and searched but I cannot find a solution to my issue, so apologies if this sounds familiar, but I am at a loss.

I have:

- Windows environment
- Apache 2.4.2
- OpenSSL 1.0.2e
- one IP address (development box: 127.0.0.1)
- multiple virtual hosts (www.site.co.uk, sub.site.co.uk, etc. )
- Genuine domain validated wildcard certificate from Comodo

I need to use the wildcard certificate for all of my virtual hosts.

I have tested the site/certificate using openssl and it verified it OK.

All the sites work fine when using the standard http over port 80.

When I enable httpd-ssl.conf, I start to get into trouble.

I have seen and tried several examples of http-ssl.conf configurations but all result in intermittent connection failures, i.e. Firefox: "*Secure Connection Failed*", IE11: "*This page cannot be displayed*". **However**, if I refresh the page (in each browser) the page displays and I can see that the certificate is valid.

From what I've read, it points to incorrect configuration of the http-ssl.conf, but I've tried the Mozilla SSL Configuration Generator (https://mozilla.github.io/server-side-tls/ssl-config-generator/), many stackoverflow answers, but still no joy.

This is my current httpd-ssl.conf file:

```
Listen  443 https

SSLStrictSNIVHostCheck off

SSLPassPhraseDialog builtin
SSLSessionCache     "shmcb:C:/Apache2.4/logs/ssl_scache(512000)"
SSLSessionCacheTimeout  300
SSLProtocol         All -SSLv2 -SSLv3 
SSLCipherSuite      ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!DSS

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:443>
    ServerName  www.site.co.uk
    ServerAlias www.site.co.uk
    DocumentRoot    C:\WebServer\Apache2.4\htdocs\www.site.co.uk

    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile "C:\WebServer\Apache2.4\conf\extra\ssl\site_wildcard.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "C:\WebServer\Apache2.4\conf\extra\ssl\site_wildcard.key"
    SSLCertificateChainFile "C:\WebServer\Apache2.4\conf\extra\ssl\site_wildcard.ca-bundle"
    SSLCACertificateFile "C:\WebServer\Apache2.4\conf\extra\ssl\addtrustexternalcaroot.crt"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:443>
    ServerName  sub.site.co.uk
    ServerAlias sub.site.co.uk
    DocumentRoot    C:\WebServer\Apache2.4\htdocs\sub.site.co.uk
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I found this solution, which did the trick for me. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17678255/using-ssl-on-two-virtualhosts/23045861#23045861

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of testing, my original comment did not solve the problem.

The certificate was configured correctly.

When running tests, on websites like ssllabs.com, the protocol and handshake results would randomly differ, even though no configuration change had taken place.

Testing/Verfiying with OpenSSL, sporadically produced the correct result, but the majority of time resulted in:

> ssl handshake failed

It turns out the culprit was that I had this in my httpd.conf file:

```
AcceptFilter https none
```

After commenting it out, it solved the problem:

```
#AcceptFilter https none
```

Answer (score 0):

when I interprete the config right, you set your V-Hosts to the local interface. When you want to serve the pages properly you need to set the hosts to accessible IPs:

```
<VirtualHost 0.0.0.0:443>
ServerName  www.site.co.uk
ServerAlias www.site.co.uk
...
</VirtualHost>
```

or to your servers IP (i.e. 192.168.23.4)

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.23.4:443>
ServerName  www.site.co.uk
ServerAlias www.site.co.uk
...
</VirtualHost>
```

Maybe this fixes your issues.

**Update:** My config looks like this (linux system)

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAdmin     admin@foo.bar
        ServerName      www.foo.bar.com
        ServerAlias     foo.bar.com
        DocumentRoot    /var/www/foo
        SSLEngine on
        SSLProtocol TLSv1
        SSLHonorCipherOrder On
        SSLCipherSuite RC4-SHA:HIGH:!ADH

        SSLCertificateChainFile         /etc/apache2/ssl/2015/intermediate.crt
        SSLCertificateFile              /etc/apache2/ssl/2015/public.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile           /etc/apache2/ssl/private.open.key
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAdmin admin@bar.com
        ServerName      www.bar.com
        ServerAlias     bar.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/bar

        SSLEngine on
        SSLProtocol TLSv1
        SSLHonorCipherOrder On
        SSLCipherSuite RC4-SHA:HIGH:!ADH

        SSLCertificateChainFile         /etc/apache2/ssl/2015/intermediate.crt
        SSLCertificateFile              /etc/apache2/ssl/2015/public.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile           /etc/apache2/ssl/private.open.key

...
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Yes, on my development box, I'm editing the Windows hosts file to associate my www.site.co.uk & sub.site.co.uk to 127.0.0.1. On my live server, the actual server IP address will be used. I'm getting the errors on both.

Comment: Have you tried to enter the SSL Settings in both V-Host config sections? My setup here has mutliple vhosts configured and each <VirtualHost /> section has it's own SSLCertificate* entry pointing to the same certificates

Comment: Yes, tried loads of different combinations, including the same wildcard certificate settings in all V-hosts. The problem even occurs if I use just one V-host.

Comment: is there a reverse-proxy or security software that might manipulate the traffic between client and server?Is tehre any security software installed on the client?

Comment: the development box is the server and client and has McAfee installed. I am currently looking into DNS/router issues as a possible cause.

Comment: Do you use an internal or an external DNS? Could you post a nslookup output for the 2 domains?